# Error applying terraform plan to create VPC endpoint in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, amazon-vpc

I am trying to create a VPC Endpoint for EC2 nodes to access S3 buckets within the same VPC in us-east-1 without having to go through the NAT Gateway. Everything seems to work fine when I setup one manually via the browser UI. I then deleted it and went to define it within my terraform config as an aws_vpc_endpoint as follows:

```
    resource "aws_vpc_endpoint" "vpc-s3-endpoint-dev" {
      vpc_id          = "${aws_vpc.dev.id}"
      service_name    = "com.amazonaws.us-east-1.s3"
      route_table_ids = ["${aws_route_table.dev-us-east-1-private.id}"]
    }
```

The plan goes fine and when I try to apply I just get this:

```
Error: Error applying plan:

1 error(s) occurred:

* aws_vpc_endpoint.vpc-s3-endpoint-dev: 1 error(s) occurred:

* aws_vpc_endpoint.vpc-s3-endpoint-dev: Error creating VPC Endpoint: InvalidServiceName: The Vpc Endpoint Service 'com.amazonaws.us-east-1.s3' does not exist
    status code: 400, request id: b062c637-ec55-4da4-8527-73b24c10fa3d
```

From what I can tell I've done everything right. That route table is the same one I associated the test VPC endpoint I successfully created manually as well. I've tried doing it by breaking out the associated route table into a separate aws_vpc_endpoint_route_table_association, and even none at all. I've also tried other aliases for us-east-1 S3 service endpoint (com.amazonaws.s3, etc). I just keep getting this same frustrating error, and I'm out of ideas.

Edit: some more context

```
   provider "aws" { 
     alias = "dev" 
     version = "= 2.12.0" 
     profile = "development" 
     region = "us-east-1" 
   }
```

```
     resource "aws_vpc" "dev" { 
       provider = "aws.dev" 
       cidr_block = "10.201.0.0/16" 
       enable_dns_support = "true" 
       enable_dns_hostnames = "true" 
     }
```

Adding the specific provider to the `aws_vpc_endpoint` resource seems to have worked.

```
aws_vpc_endpoint.vpc-s3-endpoint-dev-xxx-xxxxx: Creation complete after 6s (ID: vpce-xxxxxxxxxxxxx)

Apply complete! Resources: 1 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.
```

Comment: What does your provider config look like? Is it using `us-east-1` by default? Which region is your VPC in?

Comment: ```
provider "aws" {
  alias   = "dev"
  version = "= 2.12.0"
  profile = "development"
  region  = "us-east-1"   
}
```
...
```
resource "aws_vpc" "dev" {
  provider             = "aws.dev"
  cidr_block           = "10.201.0.0/16"
  enable_dns_support   = "true"
  enable_dns_hostnames = "true"
}
```

Edit: sorry about the formatting

Comment: Edit that into your question and then you can format it like a code block.

Comment: Also it looks like you've just missed the provider configuration from your `aws_vpc_endpoint`. You need it to match your VPC. Is there a reason you're using multiple providers here as well?

Comment: It looks like some kind of provider alias mismatch. Running your resource block with a plain AWS provider in us-east-1 works for me. When I cross region or fail to set an alias I get an error returned.

Comment: There are multiple providers because this terraform repo manages multiple environments across multiple accounts. If it helps, I have the aws_vpc_endpoint at the bottom of all the vpc/networking/routing resource definitions for the dev provider.

Comment: Does it work if you add `provider = "aws.dev" ` to the `aws_vpc_endpoint` resource?

Comment: I think that actually did it. That's frustrating as that option isn't even in the terraform resource docs for this!

Comment: That is because it is in the provider documentation. Adding it to every resource would not be very organized. You can find it here: https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/providers.html#selecting-alternate-providers

Answer (score 2):

The problem has already been solved in the comments, but I'll leave this here for future reference as it the crux of the problem here.

If you use an `alias` in a `provider` block, that provider will not be used unless you **explicitly** specify it to be, at a resource level (as done above in `provider = "aws.dev"`). The default provider in the case that you don't explicitly specify, will either be the `provider "aws"` which doesn't have an alias associated with it, and if that doesn't exist then it will just assume an implied `aws` provider.

Moral of the story, don't use an alias on your provider unless you have a good reason; Having a single codebase which publishes to multiple separate AWS accounts is a good reason.

Answer (score 2):

So, we are seeing a similar error today in us-east-1 on this:

```
data "aws_vpc_endpoint_service" "s3" {
    service = "s3"
}
```

We were able to replicate the issue with CLI:

```
aws ec2 describe-vpc-endpoint-services | jq '.ServiceDetails[] | select(.ServiceName=="com.amazonaws.us-east-1.s3")'
```

Shows there is a service with that name, but this call gets an error:

```
$ aws ec2 describe-vpc-endpoint-services --service-names com.amazonaws.us-east-1.s3
An error occurred (InvalidServiceName) when calling the DescribeVpcEndpointServices operation: The Vpc Endpoint Service 'com.amazonaws.us-east-1.s3' does not exist
```

AWS support says there's some issue with this API that is occurring in us-east-1, but not us-west-1 or us-west-2.  So it's possible your Terraform code is actually correct, but there is some other AWS API back-end issue?

Comment: Turned out our problem was a transient API issue on Amazon's side.  They fixed it shortly after our support case.